# Angular.js image 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i've a tiny problem.
I'd like to show icons from categories i get from my rest api.
To do, i use rest angular which gives me icons as designed.
My problem, is a firebug alert:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8888/app/%7B%7Bc.icon%7D%7D"
```

This is because my template is laded before api response.

```
<ul class="col-md-9 inner">
    <li ng-repeat="c in categories"><img src="{{c.icon}}" alt="{{c.name}}" ng-cloak></li>
</ul>
```

This is the piece of corresponding code in my controller

```
Category.getList().then(function(categories) {
     $scope.categories = categories;
});
```

As you can see, i've try to work with ng-cloak, i've also tried to play with ng-show="categories" but nothing more.
How can i avoid this behavior and load ng-repeat only when categories variable is populated ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

instead of

```
<img src="{{c.icon}}" alt="{{c.name}}" ng-cloak>
```

you should use ng-src:

```
<img ng-src="{{c.icon}}" alt="{{c.name}}">
```

From [ngSrc documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc):

> Using Angular markup like **{{hash}}** in a src attribute doesn't work right: **The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}}** until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The ngSrc directive solves this problem.